# a better way to loop through an array of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a model that looks as follows

```
this.Model

Model {class: undefined items: Array(0) tag: undefined launch: undefined length: undefined name: undefined Id: "de4d704a-b754-4546-b3ab-f0c131eba84a" time: "15:36" tonnage: undefined}
```

the only objects in the Model that will always have a value is Id and Time.

i have an if statement that goes through each off my objects to check if its null as follows:

```
    if ( this.Model.class == null && this.Model.name == null && this.Model.tag== null && this.Model.launch == null && this.Model.length == null && this.Model.tonnage == null && this.Model.items.length == 0) 
                {
                    //does something in here
                }
```

so i want to check if all the objects are null except time and ID, is there a better way of doing this than me using the above method in an if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a function to check about that using `Object.entries` and `Array.every`.

Perks of this solution :

- Reusable utility function.
- Works with any number of keys to ignore.
- The typing of the function will throw an error in case you specify a key to ignore that is not a part of the provided object.

---

[Playground in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawIIBtcDSaAngM4CiAHhGgA5QDiMAbmmEWQCpwBCaAciHwBDAEa40AHk6I0lKGwAmpRAG8AUIkQBtTCUQwke4nGCJOAXQBciMENyIAPonCK0wQ2kVPE2AE5+wsSS4JhgcADuYAB8PqHhUQDc6gC+0QAUcKIAVjacADSIxqQ26cam5gCU2haVNqJwcBLCSBpafmhQIH5IAPI5GFAAdGxQfjBopJk5lSOsfsTp6dqaWkUk+atazMK4IGibWrWIALyxbWswZmUkpEOGEHtuU8aIwirlZpyVlWpbax0uj1EGN9sk1ogUup-oDukgdns0KcTidbPYnM4EftkajmHAYN4AAwYxDpLFIwykKAtGgVfyBYiIABkTMQ5KGEjAAHMoCgcYhCZVwZChaloRAEKQmmgOXAuelUBgcPgOBRqHRGCw2KruHxBCJxGh0hdHu8Si4wG4PGAvIcDAoALbm+lBdKCu3Urk2VzuTyKO24YTgVDey2+m3+1acnkoUNWv12sDCB1oOPh22rACSihsAHI3AAWRQAdkJBeEAFpRMWAKwFisFusANirAGYxBXgISIABGVs9tCiYQADnLuY9MBTeZ7Nasrab49WUAQSa5qYt8YjmxShRWWlz2cX+9gKcXtVF6glYClEll8sVWDwhFuVBo9CYrHYt11AnsYgkxqrKapDmj61oZloMCOs6ASuu6S7CF6iC5uEtBoEeiCBsGsYbumkZaNGvJpuB+G2Mm65gQmWY5shhYlmWlbVnWDbNm2HZdr2-aDiOY4TlOyEznOC4eiuiEUWGJHbruqwHooGG5ie6GbOeiRAA)

---

Snippet in Javascript.

```js
function checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable(obj, keys) {
  return Object.entries(obj).every(([
    key,
    value,
  ]) => {
    // If the key has to be ignored
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      return true;
    }

    // Check the value to be nullable
    return value === null ||
      value === void 0 ||
      (value instanceof Array && value.length === 0);
  });
}

console.log(checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable({
  class: undefined,
  items: Array(0),
  tag: undefined,
  launch: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  Id: 'de4d704a-b754-4546-b3ab-f0c131eba84a',
  time: '15:36',
  tonnage: undefined,
}, [
  'Id',
  'time',
]));

console.log(checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable({
  class: undefined,
  items: Array(0),
  tag: 'nope',
  launch: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  Id: 'de4d704a-b754-4546-b3ab-f0c131eba84a',
  time: '15:36',
  tonnage: undefined,
}, [
  'Id',
  'time',
]));
```

---

```
function checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable<T extends {
  [key in keyof T]: null | undefined | Array<unknown> | unknown;
}>(obj: T, keys: (keyof T)[]): boolean {
  return Object.entries(obj).every(([
    key,
    value,
  ]) => {
    if (keys.includes(key as keyof T)) {
      return true;
    }

    return value === null ||
           value === void 0 ||
           (value instanceof Array && value.length === 0);
  });
}

console.log(checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable({
  class: undefined,
  items: Array(0),
  tag: undefined,
  launch: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  Id: 'de4d704a-b754-4546-b3ab-f0c131eba84a',
  time: '15:36',
  tonnage: undefined,
}, [
  'Id',
  'time',
]));

console.log(checkAllKeysExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable({
  class: undefined,
  items: Array(0),
  tag: 'nope',
  launch: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  name: undefined,
  Id: 'de4d704a-b754-4546-b3ab-f0c131eba84a',
  time: '15:36',
  tonnage: undefined,
}, [
  'Id',
  'time',
]));
```

Comment: i just have a quick question, since i have "this.model" that stores values. when i am calling the this.checkAllExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable() function. how do i pass this.model instance into it?

Comment: Example : In the case where `model` is an attribute of the class A. If you put `checkAllExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable` in A, you can call it as `this.checkAllExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable(this.model, [ 'Id', 'time' ])`

Comment: Example : In the case where model is an attribute of the class A. If you put checkAllExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable in an utility class called B as a static method, you can call it as `B.checkAllExceptGivenKeysToBeNullable(this.model, [ 'Id', 'time' ])`

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a bit, I came up with a solution using `Object.keys()`

```
/**
 * Checks if all of the objects values are null, except for keys in param except
 * @param obj: The object to test
 * @param except (optional): keys to omit the null check on
 */
function checkIfPropertiesNull(obj: {[key: string]: unknown}, except: string[] = []): boolean {
   const keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => !except.includes(key));
   for(const key of keys){
       if(obj[key] !== null){
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}


console.log(checkIfPropertiesNull({ id: 1, name: 'mike', city: null }, ['id', 'name'])); // true, because id and name are not checked
console.log(checkIfPropertiesNull({ id: 1, name: 'mike', city: 'Munich' }, ['id', 'name'])); // false, city isn't null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=119&pln=1&pc=1#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-eJUFl1E4BdBdpc-ThccHoH7vcg-YtiSToMBgF5eFxxHQ0IQOLLXURBLihIYBHxcuQFI0MMhcXqPkaTWaLU1Wh0uj0cP1Bs7XR6vVX-YGUyGw-6ALLVHCFP1R8TjWPx8RJqup9OZ7PS4iyqdUdS4TCCP0KAVAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let prop in Modal) {
    if (Modal.prop != time && Modal.prop != id && Modal[prop] != null) {
        return false
    }
    
}
return true
```

Return true if all properties except ID and Time are null.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have two options in this case:

1. Put your loop in a function to separate this logic to your model:

```
function checkProperties(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] !== null && obj[key] != "")
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var obj = {
    x: null,
    y: "",
    z: 1
}

checkProperties(obj) //returns false
```

2. Use Object.values and every to check your properties as an array.

```
let report = {
  property1: null,
  property2: null,
}

let result = !Object.values(report).every(o => o === null);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is generally useful to provide answer instead of redirecting to links. If you think this question is a duplicate of an existing one, you can always use comment to notify so.